# Right join a table to itself SQL

Tags: sql

This is probably really basic but I'm stuck!

I have two tables, one that shows which classes students are in and another which shows what grades each student has received. I want to find out which students, from a specific class, do not have a grade.

I wrote this code as a start point, which finds a list of the pupils in a class that do have grades:

```
SELECT mem.student_id, mem.class_id
FROM class_memberships as mem
inner join grades as gr
on mem.student_id = gr.student_id
where mem.class_id = 12 and gr.grade_type = 18
```

That works a treat, but what I actually need is the students in the class who do not have grades, rather than those that do. I thought I could right join against the memberships table as follows, but it didn't work:

```
SELECT mem.student_id, mem.class_id
FROM class_memberships as mem
inner join grades as gr
on mem.student_id = gr.student_id
right join class_memberships as mem2
on mem.student_id = mem2.student_id
where mem.class_id = 12 and gr.grade_type = 18
and mem.student_id is null
```

The above does not return any rows and I know one student does not have a grade. I followed the examples on google for SQL right joins to arrive at the above. I guess this isn't working because of the 'mem.student_id is null' clause, but all the cheatsheets on google said I needed it.

Help please! I'm a newbie to SQL (and coding in general) so this is probably really basic but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. Thanks :)

Comment: If this is sql server, Google 'SQL Server NOT EXISTS'.  Also tag which RDBMS this question is for.

Comment: Just FYI, nobody uses `RIGHT JOIN`.  `LEFT JOIN`, yes... but usually if we're tempted to use a `RIGHT JOIN` we rewrite so that it's a `LEFT JOIN`.  Start with the smallest table and find what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need a 3-way join at all:

```
SELECT student_id
FROM class_membership
LEFT JOIN grades ON (class_membership.student_id = grades.student_id
    AND class_membership.class_id = grades.class_id)
WHERE grades.student_id IS NULL
```

`class_membership` already has all the students listed, so you only need to figure out which ones DON'T have a grade, which means their "grade" entry for that class would be null.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand the guide I was trying to follow so I didn't realise I needed to look for grades that were null. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you really just need to do a `LEFT JOIN` on `grades`. `LEFT JOIN`s will show all of the `class_memberships` records whether or not a there is a corresponding `grades` record. Then you can filter out the records that don't have grades

```
SELECT mem.student_id, mem.class_id
FROM class_memberships as mem
LEFT JOIN grades as gr ON mem.student_id = gr.student_id
WHERE mem.class_id = 12
AND gr.id IS NULL --I'm not sure what your pk field is for your grades table
```

Comment: That's brilliant, I didn't know I could do gr.id is null! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mem.student_id, mem.class_id
FROM class_memberships as mem
inner join grades as gr
on mem.student_id = gr.student_id
where mem.class_id = 12 
and gr.student_id NOT EXISTS (select student_id from class_memberships where class_membership is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT m.student_id, m.class_id
FROM class_memberships m
WHERE m.class_id = 12 AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM grades g
                  WHERE g.student_id = m.student_id AND gr.grade_type = 18
                 );
```

However, I am very suspicious about your data structure.  I would expect `grades` to have a link to the class as well as the student:

```
SELECT m.student_id, m.class_id
FROM class_memberships m
WHERE m.class_id = 12 AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM grades g
                  WHERE g.student_id = m.student_id AND g.class_id = m.class_id
                 );
```

However, I might be misunderstanding the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

this breaks it

where mem.class_id = 12 and gr.grade_type = 18

and why join to the same table twice?

```
SELECT mem.student_id, mem.class_id
FROM class_memberships as mem
left join grades as gr
       on mem.student_id = gr.student_id
      and gr.grade_type = 18
where gr.student_id is null
  and mem.class_id = 12
```